# Is multiplication by zero a special case?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2013, multiplication

I'm writing a code where optimization is a real issue, I really need to get this piece of code running as fast as possible.

So I have somthing like:

a is a double and x is an int.
in my specific case x is always 2 or 3

```
double c1[3] = {5345.4364654, 43346.6876978, 1224324.654756};
double c2[3] = {49876.642543678, 1104.57576756};
...
..
if (x>2)
   a = c1[0]*x*x*x-c1[1]*x*x+c1[2]*x;
else
   a = c2[0]*x*x+c2[1]*x;
```

I wonder if it will be faster if I remove the if..else and do something like

```
double c [2][3] = { 
                      {5345.4364654, 43346.6876978 , 1224324.654756},
                      {0           ,49876.642543678, 1104.575767561}
                     };

a = c1[x-2][0]*x*x*x-c1[x-2][1]*x*x+c1[x-2][2]*x;
```

it seemes to me that the second code would run faster if multiplication by zero is treated as a "special case" by the compiler but I'm not sure about that

if any of you guys have an idea plz help :)
Many thanks

Comment: if `x` is 0 then `a` is 0

Comment: yes sorry I made a mistake when writing my question :(
x should would have a value other then zero and one.

Comment: It *might* be faster, but not because the compiler treats 0 as a special case, but because you're avoiding a branch. You'd need to measure to find out.

Comment: Probably you mean something like
    `int k = (x>0) ? 0 : 1;  a = c[k][0]*x*x*x-c[k][1]*x*x+c[k][2]*x;`

Comment: @molbdnilo : so you think the branch will cost more then three multiplications??

Comment: @grep: yes I mainly want to know which would be faster having the branch (if...else) or the three multiplications by zero

Comment: @Gibnem actually you only need 3 additions and 1 multiplication.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl it was my mistake in the original question, sorry

Comment: "x is always 2 or 3" So why not pre-calculate the two possible results? You can't get faster or more accurate than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays multiplication is really fast, so avoiding branches is probably more important than skipping one multiplication by 0.

I'd factorise the equation like below though:

```
double c [2][3] = { 
                      {5345.4364654, 43346.6876978 , 1224324.654756},
                      {0           ,49876.642543678, 1104.575767561}
                     };

a = ((c1[x-2][0]*x-c1[x-2][1])*x+c1[x-2][2])*x;
```

Note that if the array `c` really is a compile time constant (and if you help the compiler by making it const) you might be able to hint the compiler to pre-compute values for x = 2 and x = 3 like so:

```
switch (x)
{
  case 2:
    a = ((c1[x-2][0]*x-c1[x-2][1])*x+c1[x-2][2])*x;
    break;
  case 3:
    a = ((c1[x-2][0]*x-c1[x-2][1])*x+c1[x-2][2])*x;
    break;
  default:
    // this should never happen
}
```

That might intice the compiler just to compile the answer directly.

It's quite possible this might work as well:

```
switch (x)
{
  case 2:
  case 3:
    a = ((c1[x-2][0]*x-c1[x-2][1])*x+c1[x-2][2])*x;
    break;
  default:
    // this should never happen
}
```

However if `c` really is a compile time constant and `x` really is 2 or 3 you're only got two inputs and two results so you might as well just work out both answers on your calculator and hard code them in a switch statement if you're really worried about the speed.

Comment: Many thanks @Clinton I really like the idea of factoring
Do you think also that "Switch" will be faster then "if" even though it's not a long list of cases? I knew "switch is always a better option then multiple "if...else if...else if....else if" but here it's only one "if else"... what do you think?

Comment: If you can use switch it's likely no slower than if/else and possibly faster. But that only works if your comparisons are "equals". Keep in mind that compilers are smart, as they've been written by lots of people with combined intelligence greater than both you and me. If you want fast code you just have to make sure you're not getting in the way of the compiler doing it's job, which generally just involved saying exactly what you want.

Comment: For example, you might find your compiler may have factored the code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually go with your first form but try to make it easier.

> a is a double and x is an int. in my specific case x is always 0 or 1 but I can't have it as a boolean (true/false) it base to be int!

There's a lot we can do since we know that it can only be 0 or 1.

1. we can get rid of the whole `c2` case, since multiplying with 0 will always result in 0 anyways.
2. if `x` is 1 multiplying multiple times with x won't change anything. Multiplying `y` with 1 always returns y.

Now we get something like:

```
double c1[3] = {5345.4364654, 43346.6876978, 1224324.654756};
a = (c1[0]-c1[1]+c1[2]) * x;
```

Comment: yes that would be true, but I already corrected my question and @mgetz did too. so x is not really 0 or 1 but it's still an int
thanks any way :)

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is exactly equal to `0`, then `a` is also `0`, it is just a polynomial. If you really want, you can make an extra case

```
else if (x == 0)
    a = 0;
```

But you will likely see no observable increase in speed. This smells like unnecessary micro-optimzation.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake when writing my question as I tried to simplify my code, I just corrected it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding jumps is usually a good thing for performance because every conditional jump disturbs the CPU pipeline. It's better to do some extra (easily parallelized) linear computation.

Comment: I will try measuring the run time and let you know what I get.
thanks

Comment: tested with VS2013 and got very similar results:

1) the version with if...else running either 2nd or 3rd order poly. over 3000000000 iterations had a total run time of 10456 ms

2) the version without if...else and running always 3rd order poly. over again 3000000000 iterations had a total run time of 10256 ms

Still don't know for sure what should I use :(

Answer (score 1):

You could precalculate some values ahead of time.
Given

> a = c1[x-2][0]*x*x*x-c1[x-2][1]*x*x+c1[x-2][2]*x;

The expression `x-2` is used 3 times.

If x is either 2 or three, you should plug them into the equation and simplify:

```
switch (x)
{
  case 2:
    a = c1[0][0]*8 - c1[0][1] * 4 + c1[0][2]* 2;
    break;
  case 3:
    a = c1[1][0]*27 - c1[1][1] * 9 + c1[1][2] * 3;
    break;
}
```

Although you may get more performance performing all multiplication first, then addition:

```
  const double term1 = c1[x-2][0]*x*x*x;
  const double term2 = c1[x-2][1]*x*x;
  const double term3 = c1[x-2][2]*x;
  a = term1 + term2 + term;
```

Combine above with some prefetching, may get better performance:

```
  // Prefetch
  const double v0 = c1[x-2][0];
  const double v1 = c1[x-2][1];
  const double v2 = c1[x-2][2];

  // Mulitply
  const double t1 = v0 * x * x * x;
  const double t2 = v1 * x * x;
  const double t3 = v2 * x;

  // Sum
  a = t1 + t2 + t3;
```

The best method is to code this up and look at the assembly language.
Also not the use of `const`.  The use of `const` will help the compiler perform better optimization.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMatthews I like this idea of Prefetch->Multiply->Sum
the Prefetch makes sense for me, then you don't have to go back and forth accessing the array, but what about performing the multiplication first and sum after? can you explain that for me or just suggest some reading material? Many thanks

Comment: Performing all multiplication together may be able provoke some optimization by the compiler or the inner workings of the processor.  You may be able to detect a point for parallel execution.  Similarly with the addition.  Although some processors can multiply and add with one instruction.  This is why I suggest looking at the assembly language to what the truth is.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!